# Subversion list of modified files with updated version in repo

Tags: svn

How do I know if my modified local copy of files have an updated version in repository?

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using the command line client or a gui one?

Comment: I what to know both in command line or in TSVN. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLI: `svn status -u`

```
   The out-of-date information appears in the ninth column (with -u):
      '*' a newer revision exists on the server
      ' ' the working copy is up to date
```

TortoiseSVN:  CM - "Check for modification" - "Check repository" button